# font-mfizz displaying icons as square

Tags: html, css, icons

Im using [font-mfizz](http://fizzed.com/oss/font-mfizz) for icons on my site and for whatever reason they always appear as squares. I have all the fonts installed in all different formats and im still getting no results.
here is the code that I have

`<i class="icon-javascript-alt"></i>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. When you download the font-mfizz package, simply paste all files (css, eot, svg, ttf, woff) to your project folder.